# WINAPI: WTSRegisterSessionNotification - NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION vs NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS?

Tags: winapi

RE: [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsregistersessionnotification)

Can someone explain what the difference between these flag options actually means?

> NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION
>
> Only session notifications involving the session attached to by the
> window identified by the hWnd parameter value are to be received.

> NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS
>
> All session notifications are to be received.

Is sessions a log in session a user is logged in to?

Is this like having different sessions on terminal server vs normal Windows workstation?

Comment: "*Is this like having different sessions on terminal server*" - yes. Each user login, whether locally or remotely, runs in a separate session. Each window belongs to the session it is created in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, does C++ builder not have wtsapi32.h ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I use the WTS functions in C++Builder projects, works fine for me.

Comment: Your right - it's just the code highlighter saying things don't exist but it compiles.   Have a bunch of those.